# -join operator on a variable for a parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

```
function Get-Diskinfo {
    param(
        [string[]] $Computername = 'XEUTS001',
        [string[]] $drive = 'c:'
    )

    $a = "-join $Computername[1..3]" 

    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk `
            -Filter "DeviceID = '$drive'" `
            -ComputerName $Computername `
            -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential ayan-$a) |
        Select-Object `
            @{n='Size'; e={$_.size / 1gb -as [int]}},
            @{n='free';e={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int]}},
            @{n='% free';e={$_.freespace / $_.size *100 -as [int]}} |
        Format-Table -AutoSize 
}
```

I wrote this function to get some details about specific disks. However, I have to run them remotely and in a multi-domain environment. We have different usernames for computers in different OU's. I wanted the script to be able to take the username from the computername itself. The usernames are in this format `---- "name"+ "first 3 letters of the computername"` which is the OU name. I am able to get the `-Join` method to work normally. However, it doesn't work if the variable is a parameter in a function. Here the username shows up as `"ayan--join xeuts001[1..3]"` when I want it to show up as `"ayan-xeu"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is just a string that happens to contain a variable (which is expanded). Inside a string you are *not* in expression mode, so you cannot use operators. They just get embedded string content like you see there. What you want is probably:

```
$a = -join $Computername[1..3]
```

But that isn't correct, as it will yield `oob` for a computer name `Foobar`. If you want the first three letters, you'd need

```
$a = -join $Computername[0..2]
```

or even simpler (and easier to read, and faster):

```
$a = $Computername.Substring(0, 3)
```

P.S.: I also took the liberty of reformatting your original code, it was a horrible mess to read.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting, @Joey. The substring option is better than "-join". I missed it when looking for the list of methods in "$a | gm"  

However "$a = -join $Computername[1..3]" yields the expected output if tested outside of a script. I just couldn't get it to work inside the script.....

Thanks again..

Comment: Also, 

"-Credential (Get-Credential -Credential ayan-$a)"......works

But
"-Credential (Get-Credential -Credential ayan-$Computername.Substring(0, 3))"

....doesnt

Comment: `Get-Credential ayan-$($Computername.Substring(0, 3))` would work. Keep in mind that arguments to cmdlets are basically the same as double-quoted strings when it comes to variables and stuff (not quite, because you can trigger mode reevaluation with parentheses, but close enough for this).